# Getting child component values in a custom web control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom web control having two labels. On the display page I want to modify the text of one of the labels depending on a condition.
How to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how your control in defined. If the label is public you simply access the label through the control instance

```
if(condition)
    mycontrol.label.Text = "Some text";
```

If it private you will need a public method in the control to change the text, e.g.

```
void SetLabelText(string text)
{
    this.label.Text = text;
}
```

and then call the method

```
if(condition)
    mycontrol.SetLabelText("Some text");
```

Comment: This is my control code.Plz suggest how to make label public

 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Red" Width="300px" Height="300px">

<asp:Label ID="Labelleft" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 15px; top: 19px; position: absolute; height: 17px;" Text="txt1" Width="100px" BackColor="Yellow"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="Labelright" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 101px; top: 19px; position: absolute" Text="txt2" Width="100px" BackColor="Gold">
</asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>